# jQuery collision detection between divs

Tags: javascript

I have a big circle (my first `<div>`) which is following my mouse, and every second spawning white circles (a bunch of `<div>`s) with global class and listed IDs.

I tried so many methods (`bigcircle.x - whitecircle.x`, etc.) How do I do this?

Comment: Try calculating the distance between the centroids of each circle and making sure if it's less than their combined radii.

Comment: It'll be easier for people to help you out if you shared the code